# How do i copy files starting with HYPHEN using power shell script...?

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script that will copy files from one location to another... But few files/documents in my source location were starting with "-" in their names, they couldn't get copied to the destination..bcoz of that hyphen symbol in starting. What change can make my code to ignore the symbol HYPHEN and make my files get copied to my destination location. Files that don't have HYPHEN in starting of their names got copied successfully. I can't replace or remove these hyphen's from the doc name it has to be there and i want to copy them.

This is the code i tried so far.

```
**$newstreamreader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("Z:\RedirectedDesktop\TextDocuments\Hyphen.txt")  #MY SOURCE LOCATION THAT HAVE PHYSICAL FILES PATH
$eachlinenumber = 1
while (($readeachline =$newstreamreader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
$string1="Y:\"+$readeachline  #LOCATION OF PHYSICAL FILES
if (Test-Path -Path $string1){
$LogFile = "Z:\RedirectedDesktop\LogFileCheckPresent.txt"  #GENERATES LOG FILE IF FILE PRESENT PHYSICALLY
$Message = $readeachline+",True";
$Message >> $LogFile;

$string2="Z:\RedirectedDesktop\Sample"  #DESTINATION
$string3= Split-Path $readeachline -leaf
$string1=$string1.substring(0,$string1.LastIndexOf('\'))


Write-Host "$string1"
Write-Host "$string2"
Write-Host "$string3"
$execution =robocopy $string1 $string2 $string3;
if($execution -match 'ERROR'){
$execution | out-file "Z:\RedirectedDesktop\test_logerror.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append  # CREATES A ERROR LOG FILE IF THERE IS AN ERROR IN COPYING
}
else{
$execution | out-file "\Z:RedirectedDesktop\test_log1.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append   # CREATES A TEST LOG FILE IF THERE IS NO ERROR IN COPYING
}
}
else{
$LogFile="Z:\RedirectedDesktop\LogFileCheckNotPresent.txt"   #GENERATES LOG FILE IF FILE NOT PRESENT PHYSICALLY
$Message = $readeachline+",False";
$Message >> $LogFile;
}
Write-Host "$eachlinenumber $readeachline"
$eachlinenumber++
}
$newstreamreader.Dispose()**
```

**
ERROR I GOT **

---

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "-2 Quote wired second company india private Limited.msg"

```
   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?
```

****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

Comment: Could be a quoting issue. For debugging, print the whole robocopy command with all the parametes to console and see if you can run the command from shell.

Comment: @vonPryz No, it's not a quoting issue. Let me tell u the structure of the document path.    FOLDER1/FOLDER2/FOLDER3/-DOCNAME.EXTENSION. I just want to know is there any command that will ignore this hyphen and let the document be copied. And there are few hyphen's in the middle of document name but they got copied successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is specific to **`robocopy.exe`**:

**If a directory-path or file-name argument *starts with* `-` (HYPHEN-MINUS, [`U+002D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d)), it is *invariably* interpreted as an *option*** (such as `-MIRROR` - RoboCopy accepts `/` and `-` interchangeably as option prefixes) - whether that path or name is double-quoted or not.

**Workaround**:

- For the ***directory* path arguments** (the first two): **Make the paths start with a *different* character**, for which you have two options:

  - Pass a *full* file path (which by definition doesn't start with `-`).
  - *Prepend* `.\` to a relative path / directory name; e.g.:
- For the ***file name* argument** (the third one):

  - There is **no *direct* workaround I'm aware of, only a *suboptimal* one that runs the risk of *false positives***:

    - **Replace the initial `-` with wildcard character `?`**
    - While this will match your `-`-prefixed file, it may also match other files, if their name is the same except for the first character.

Applied to your case:

```bash
robocopy $string1 $string2 ('?' + $string3.Substring(1))
```

Comment: I thought this would definitly work. But, it didn't  as u said I added this .\ before my directory name which has physical files... After making changes when I ran the script it generated  a file that the files were not present at the location. I mean it executed the last else part in my code which I mentioned in the question.  The change I did, $string1=".\Y:\"+$readeachline. And I tried this as well $string1="./Y:\"+$readeachline. Kindly let me know did I tried wrongly?

Comment: @Beqadar, please see my update - I didn't realize that the `-` prefix is in the third, file-name-only argument in your case.

Comment: Thank u soo much. It's working now... But out of 14 files 8 got copied to destination becoz as u mentioned  it's considering the FILE NAME only instead of full path, that's y the files with similar names were overriding and treated as duplicates. So out of 5 similar named files only 1 got copied.  I will find a way to copy all the docs at one run. Once again thank u soo much @mklement0

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Beqadar; my pleasure. Sounds like you'll have to rename your files to fully solve your problem.

Comment: If I can rename the documents, Instead of doing all these for that hyphen, I could have renamed/removed those hyphens from the starting of the doc names 